# What is the optimal approach for handling multiple Tables in R which are connected?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, data.table

```
library(data.table)
```

If you have say 3 tables in a star schema. something like this. Where I have a dummy table **dt1** which is dependent upon dt2 and dt3

```
dt1 <- data.table( x1 = 1:10, y1 = 11:20)
dt2 <- data.table( x2 = 1:10, y2 = letters[11:20])
dt3 <- data.table( x3 = letters[1:10], y3 = 11:20)

dt1[dt2, on = c( x1 = "x2")]
dt2[dt1, on = c( x2 = "x1")]
dt3[dt1, on = c( y3 = "y1")]
```

In the above scenario you will have to remember almost 4 combinations for every query. along with their order. Imagine a scenario where you have 10 or 20 of such tables directly from a database or csvs.

```
dt1[dt2]
dt2[dt1]
dt1[dt3]
dt3[dt1]
```

One approach is writing a function like this.

```
rememberJoin <- function(table1, table2){
  if( 
    table1 == "dt1" && 
    table2 == "dt2"
  ){
    return(c( x1 = "x2"))
  } else if(
    table1 == "dt2" && 
    table2 == "dt1"
  ){
    return(c( x2 = "x1"))
  } else if(
    table1 == "dt3" && 
    table2 == "dt1"
  ){
    return(c( y3 = "y1"))
  } else if(
    table1 == "dt1" && 
    table2 == "dt3"
  ){
    return(c( y1 = "y3"))
  }
}


dt1[dt2, on = rememberJoin("dt1", "dt2")]
dt2[dt1, on = rememberJoin("dt2", "dt1")]
dt3[dt1, on = rememberJoin("dt3", "dt1")]
```

But the entire solution is hacky and have too many if statements and is very hard to read or debug. I used another solution by creating named list.

```
Join <- list(
dt1dt2 = c( x1 = "x2"),
dt2dt1 = c( x2 = "x1"),
dt3dt1 = c( y3 = "y1"),
dt1dt3 = c( y1 = "y3")
)

dt1[dt2, on = Join$dt1dt2]
dt2[dt1, on = Join$dt2dt1]
dt3[dt1, on = Join$dt3dt1]
```

It works just fine. But I am still not sure if this is the optimal solution or is there any package which has join aware tables. Any suggestion or alternative will do. I have very complex dataset I am working with more than 25 tables. I am looking for a solution.

Comment: could you elaborate on why there are 4 combinations? what's the logic behind y3 matching y1 but then x1 matching x2?

Comment: It's just a dummy data I created to show that dt1 depends upon dt2 and dt3... so you can have 2 tables joining in 2 ways thus 4 ways

Comment: dt1[dt2] ;
dt2[dt1] ;
dt1[dt3] ;
dt3[dt1] ;

Comment: I edited the question to explain it's a dummy data

Comment: I assume by depend you mean they share elements? and that you would like to check if any of your 25 tables share elements with each other? Please explain what you would like to do with the 25 tables. Or maybe youre trying to just merge these 25 tables removing the common elements?

Comment: All I want to do for now is explore the data. It's entire database snapshot I have access to. And I have imported them in multiple csvs.

Comment: I just don't know what to do with them. Thus its hard to keep track of all the joins in tables.

Comment: rememberJoin function is just meant to return the join vector. So I am passing data table name like a string. If you have any other optimal solutions I would love to see them.

Comment: Is there a package to facilitate arbitrary joining like this? I don't think so. In my experience, the most straight-forward way to facilitate/automate joining like this is to either (1) be explicit, typically best; or (2) assume that shared column names are the joining columns. The latter can be problematic, but it's about the only way to really automate in a generic sense (and requires knowing this when designing the tables).

Comment: I kinda had a feeling that there is no such package. I was looking for ideas like if you were to do this how would you approach such problem.

Comment: You can check dwtools package which has a function to batch join, there is a FR for that in data.table package. You can put your use case there so we will ensure it won't be missed when implementing that feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out about a package that is some what related to the same issue. Mentioning it here just for the reference.

https://krlmlr.github.io/dm/articles/dm-visualization.html

Its keeping a record for all the joins for local r data frames. Must look at it.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at binding all of the lookup tables together.

```
dt_dummy = dt1
dt_lookup = rbindlist(list(dt2, dt3[, .(y2 = y3, x2 = x3)]), idcol = 'ID')

dt_dummy[dt_lookup, on = .(x1 = x2), nomatch = 0L]
dt_dummy[dt_lookup, on = .(y1 = x2), nomatch = 0L]
```

If you must have a function call, this takes advantage of the laziness of R's evaluation. It requires you providing lookup tables ahead of time but is more in line with your question. Note to reduce logical statements, this solution always reorders your inputs. That is, `rememberJoin2(dt1, dt2)` evaluates the same as `rememberJoin2(dt2, dt1)` - it would look too messy otherwise.

```
dt1_lookup = c('x1', 'y1')
dtx_lookup = c('x2', 'y3')

rememberJoin2 <- function(t1, t2){
  l = list(substitute(t1), substitute(t2))

  #extract the number from dt#
  n <- vapply(l, function(x) as.integer(gsub("dt", "", deparse(x))), 0L)

  if(n[1] == n[2]) stop('must provide different data.tables to join')

  r <- rank(n)

  eval(
    substitute(X[Y, on = .(Xkey == Ykey)],
               list(X = l[[r[1]]],
                    Y = l[[r[2]]],
                    Xkey = as.name(dt1_lookup[max(n) - 1]), 
                    Ykey = as.name(dtx_lookup[max(n) - 1])
                    )
               )
    )
}

rememberJoin2(dt1, dt2)
rememberJoin2(dt2, dt1)
```